# Generating similar but different vectors

Tags: matlab, vector

I want to generate 100 vectors each of size 1x7. I have the following code currently, but when I plot it, it seems to be too linearly spaced. Is there a way to achieve a similar result only rougher?

```
P = randi([7 12],100,7)'/10.* repmat(randn(1,7),100,1)';
```

Comment: Btw, when you talk about a picture you don't like, it's a good idea to show it.

Comment: "too linearly spaced" for what? It is unclear from your question what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

You may use different distribution for the randomizing part. **randi** is using uniformly distribution. You can use **rng** function to control random number generation. There are different generators like :

```
'twister'   Mersenne Twister
'combRecursive' Combined Multiple Recursive
'multFibonacci' Multiplicative Lagged Fibonacci
```

as an example:

```
rng('shuffle')
rng(1);
A = rand(2,2);
rng(2);
B = rand(2,2);
```

it produces different numbers each time.

check this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) for more info.